# how to call fitBounds on leaflet angular

Tags: leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

How can I call fitbounds on a map with angular leaflet?  I saw a post somehwere to look for the map binding event but couldn't find any sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('MapController', ['$scope', 'leafletData',
    function($scope, leafletData) {
            leafletData.getMap().then(function(map) {
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
            });
    }
]);
```

and check out 
[Dynamically changing Leaflet map bounds in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28102376/dynamically-changing-leaflet-map-bounds-in-angular)